# Why the camera fails "sometimes" in reading a text with Google mobile vision?

Tags: android, camera, barcode, detection, android-vision

I'm using google mobile vision library for barcode detection, my problem is **sometimes** the camera decodes wrongly the barcode values.

This is the content of the codeBar for exemple: **BLR16001692**

The camera return this value: **B%%'60(1692**

By the way I'm using for test: **Huawei TIT-U02 device with Android 5.1**

What could be the reason of this error?

update:

The type or format of barcode which I'm using is the same always: 3 characters+ 8 digits ex: BLR12345678.

I get the error above only with the Huawei TIT-U02, 
 with another device like Huawei-G730 I get a long series of digits , ex: 2567476459569

The error occurred only at the starting of the application, I mean the first try of barcode detection.

Comment: First, monitor the conditions on which it fails to better define the "sometimes". Lighting, angle, type of barcode, what you are reading it off (paper, screen, ...?), ... Also, maybe post some code.

Comment: check the update please

Comment: Which barcode format is being used?

Comment: @clownba0t it's 128 code Format.